# How to execute ansible playbook in Jenkins

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins, ansible

I want to run a playbook using Jenkins. I have Docker installed in windows 10 machine. Through Docker I brought up a local Jenkins, and I installed GIT and Ansible plugin in it.

Now if the Jenkins job gets triggered, my playbook is getting downloaded from GIT to my Jenkins workspace. From my workspace I am trying to run the playbook.
When I trigger the build job I am facing issue after checkout from GIT as follows:

```
[MyFirstJob] $ sshpass ******** /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /usr/bin -l "${group} /hostname" -f 5 -u dinesh -k
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sshpass" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MyFirstJob"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
```

I do not have Ansible installed in my local machine. Do I need to install it in my local ? Or any other steps to run my ansible playbook through my local Jenkins. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See if [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42814) helps you. You need to make changes in the ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the main error you are seeing, it looks like you don't have the `sshpass` program installed where Jenkins is running, in a container it sounds like.

I say "where Jenkins is running" because it seems like you are confusing the execution space where the container is running with your local system's execution space where docker is running.

Yes, you will need to have ansible installed but it needs to be installed inside the container where Jenkins is running.  Jenkins won't be able to access any programs running on your local system if its running inside a container.  You can share filesystems and some processes, but essentially the container needs to have Jenkins, `sshpass`, *and* ansible installed.

Comment: I did not find a proper way to install ansible in windows through search. Can I get a way to install ansible in windows 10 docker environment ?

Comment: The easiest way to install ansible is with Python's `pip` command. Install python and then run `pip install ansible`. You will need to make sure ansible is on your path or use the complete path to the install location when you call it in your script. But also look into  installing sshpass.